# How to extract a numeric date in a text field with Excel?

Tags: excel, string, date

I have Excel cells with dates and text mixed like this (in the same cell) : 

`20200419: blablablah
20200511: blablablah
20200513: blablablah`

How can I extract the last date "20200513" (for comparaison with actual date) ?

Thanks,
++

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sample data point is located in cell `A1`, we can try:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND(":", A1) - 1)
```

This would return the left 8 characters corresponding to the date.  To do the comparison, you might have to take the additional step of casting the column to date type.